# How to hide value labels in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, android-studio, charts, label, mpandroidchart

How to remove the label in a`BarChart`. I have attached screenshot with what I want to remove marked in red. **How do I remove that number?**

Here is screenshot:

[image: a bar chart with a label marked in red]

```
                BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "");
                BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
                barChart.setData(data);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you need to add below line to hide label

```
dataSet.setDrawValues(false);
```